# JSONObject won't save to SQL database

Tags: android, sql, json

I'm using Asyncs to download and parse a JSON from a website to save in a SQL database. I have successfully downloaded the JSONArray and verified on my logcat it exists. However, when I go to parse the JSONArray into a **courseCode** and **courseTitle** column, then store it to my SQL table called "courses"... nothing actually gets saved.

I've verified the data from the website has been downloaded using a content values (named "menuValues"). I must be using the wrong approach to save to a SQL database or a JSONArray object is not appropriate?

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            InputStream content = new BufferedInputStream(
                    urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return resulting = stringBuilder.toString();
    }



@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    databaseHelper databaseHelper = new databaseHelper(myActivity);
    SQLiteDatabase db=databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
       String jsonDataString = resulting;  // Returned from doInBackGround
        JSONArray menuItemsJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonDataString);

        db.beginTransaction();

        for(int i =0; i<menuItemsJsonArray.length(); i++){
            String courseCode;
            String courseTitle;

            JSONObject menuDataString = menuItemsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            courseCode = menuDataString.getString("courseCode");
            courseTitle=menuDataString.getString("courseTitle");

            ContentValues menuValues = new ContentValues();
            menuValues.put("course_code1", courseCode);
            menuValues.put("course_name1", courseTitle);

            db.insert("courses", null, menuValues); // Not saving here
            Log.v("DATABASE INSERTION", "NEW ID " + menuValues); // Verified menuValues has correct info..... V/DATABASE INSERTION: NEW ID course_name1=Intro to Comp. course_code1=COMP9

        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();


    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("MESSAGE", e.getMessage(), e);
    }finally{
        db.endTransaction();

    }
    db.close();

}
```

Comment: check `menuItemsJsonArray.length()`

Comment: Check if table exists and database and table creation was done correct

Comment: You do two `db.beginTransaction` but only one `db.endTransaction` - and on some databases transactions nest - try removing one of them and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Store it as a string _menuValues.toString()_

Comment: check your array size and also check  tags when you are getting values for coursecode and coursetitle